# Github Pages 404 on node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages

I am trying to render my GitHub repo on the Publisher-Subscriber module with JavaScript using GitHub pages. The `gh-pages` branch looks fine. However, the mustache code does not render on my project on GitHub Pages. It looks like this :

[image]

GitHub Repository : https://github.com/ajhalthor/pubsub-application

Github Pages Repo for this project : https://ajhalthor.github.io/pubsub-application/

The GitHub Repository also has the `node_modules` folder, so it should be self sufficient. Mustache, jQuery & Bootstrap are included in this folder, so there are no external links or CDNs.

**Main Question** : Why isn't mustache rendering even though all paths are specified relative to the project's main folder?

Comment: https://ajhalthor.github.io/pubsub-application/node_modules/mustache/mustache.js should give you a hint.

Comment: better yet use rawgit.

Comment: To your first comment: It seems like the `node_modules` folder is not found. But it is a part of my repository. So why isn't this found ?

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Github pages uses a version of Jekyll that ignores `node_modules` folder by default.

According to this [blog article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3181-including-node-modules-and-vendors-folders-in-your-github-pages-site.htm). You can do the following:

> Create an empty `.nojekyll` text file in the root of the gh-pages branch.

You can also refer to this [announcement by github](https://github.com/blog/2277-what-s-new-in-github-pages-with-jekyll-3-3) which talks about the update that is responsible for this behavior.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I also tried rawgit and that gave me a url for development & production. According to you, how is that better?

Comment: It isn't better, but its an option.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up mate

Comment: Thanks a lot, nice catch!