# Github Pages returns 404 Error when trying to grab paper.js resource

Tags: javascript, github-pages

I saw some other posts but it seems like I still can't get it to work, I made sure that the path exists inside the project but it doesn't seem to be able to grab it despite others working.

Specifically, as seen in the console in the page
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
for paper-full.js:1

The offending github page:
https://eriejar.github.io/SoundOfLife/gameoflife.js

The repo: https://github.com/Eriejar/SoundOfLife

Any help would be appreciated

I have tried the following URLs:

> src="~/node_modules/paper/dist/paper-full.js"
>
> src="./node_modules/paper/dist/paper-full.js"
>
> src="/node_modules/paper/dist/paper-full.js"
>
> src="node_modules/paper/dist/paper-full.js"

Answer (score 0):

GitHub pages ignores the node_modules folder by default. Copy paper-full.js out of the folder or try the solution provided here: [Github Pages 404 on node_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481269/github-pages-404-on-node-modules-folder)